# alert response returns undefined on JQuery Ajax success callback

Tags: ajax, laravel, get

I have a un issue with displaying items of a category with ajax. I can't understand how i could get the data.

What's wrong with my code?
`item-controller.php`

```php
public function findByCategory($cat,$visibility)
{
  return Item::where("item_category_id","=",1)
             ->where("is_visible_".$visibility, "=",1)->get()->all();
}
```

Javascript

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn-itemCategory', function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: "api/item/findByCategory/{cat}",
      data:{cat: 'item_category_id' },  
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'get',
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      },
   });
```

`Blade View`

```html
<div class="btn-container flex-horiz flex-justify-center ">
    @foreach ($itemCategories as $pc)
    <button id='btn-itemCategory' class="btn-large" type="button"
        name="button">{{__("itemCategory.$pc->slug")}}</button>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="card-container flex-horiz flex-justify-center ">
    @foreach ($items as $item)
    @if ($item->capacity%2)
    <div id="card" class="card">
        <div class=" card-front ">
            <div>
                <h4>{{__("item.$item->slug")}}</h4>
                <p>{{$item->capacity}} m³</p>
                <img src="{{$urlImgitem}}/{{$item->image}}.png" alt="item">
                <p>{{__("item.front_text")}}</p>
                <h4>{{-- $item->prix --}}</h4>
                <button class=" btn-action" type="button" name="button">{{__("item.front_btn")}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

the data  alert is "object object" I am supposed to get items list.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, there are several issues with your code, but tell us what do you expect the result to be and what errors are you getting

Comment: First, `$visibility` is undefined in the controller, you need to set the variable to some value that you want which corresponds to a column in your database

Comment: Hi @CaddyDZ  , thank you for your answer , i correct my code and add what i have as answer from the alert .  normally t should be a list of items , I mean alla items that get as category number  1, no ?

Comment: Try `alert(data.response)`

Comment: @CaddyDZ  
i wrote it this way :
success: function(data){
        alert(data.response);
      },
and the answer was "undefined"

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? because you should

Comment: @caddyDz ,  No 

Comment: Okay here are few steps to get started fixing your code, `return Item::where("item_category_id", "=", $cat)->all();` because visibility is not passed in the request

Comment: `url: "/api/item/findByCategory/1",` because `{cat}` is not a valid url

Comment: Aha thanks i'll try that. But if i want the items of each category i click on . How to get the "id" in the place of "1" in my url ?

Comment: You would need something **LIKE** `document.getElementByID('item_category_id')` but I need to see the full HTML to tell you how to do it exactly

Comment: @CaddyDZ iedited my code js  (i'am working with jquery ) and I added a part of my blade.php file (html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are getting the data right. You just don't know how to use it.
The data coming from Laravel response is usually in JSON format that you can't display using the alert() method.
Try using console.log() and then do Inspect the page.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-itemCategory', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/item/findByCategory/{cat}",
        data:{cat: 'item_category_id' },  
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'get',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

and you should see the data returned back in this section.
[image]

Comment: oh how silly is me ; really thank you . i just forget about the json point

Comment: Glad the answer helped you.